# How to create a custom percent (%) shortcut like %appdata%?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, appdata

Is it possible? 
If so, how? 
Can it be done in `CMD`?

Existing shortcuts examples :

```
%appdata%
%temp%
%userprofile%
```

Comment: Those are environment variables, and yes you can create your own.  A little Googling will go a long way here.  Take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist and ask a more specific question.

Comment: I Googled fast, but apparently I didn't known that it was named an `environment variable`, thanks for the tip ;). Anyway, now this page will be indexed in Google with my title and tags, good thing. 
*Also, why did you commented instead of answering ?

Comment: `set /?` will give you a good starting point

Comment: I left a comment since I didn't figure "google it" was a particularly good answer (so not worth the reputation bump :-)), but since you just didn't know your search term, I've added a better fleshed-out answer to help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are environment variables and you can set your own, yes.

You can set them within a script or at cmd prompt with `set`, and you can make "global" environment variables by going to System Properties/Advanced and clicking the Environment Variables button.  Variables added there will be available to all applications.  If you have existing cmd windows open, though, they won't get the global variables - you will need to open new windows to make these variables available.

Comment: Also, we need to click `Ok` to close the `Environment Variables` window to apply changes

Answer (score 0):

This should help someone 
try %AppData%